# Highlight active page menu item in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, navigation, highlight

I need some help to make active the current page in my Wordpress menu in my theme. Just like on this site of mine: http://hegeduoktatas.tk

The code I'm trying to implement is the following (the things the code does is not interesting, I'm just trying to work, and I customize it afterwards):

```
.main-navigation .current-menu-item a{
color: #ffd696;
background: #632818;
}

.main-navigation .current_page_item a{
    text-decoration:underline;
    background:#666;
}
```

I tried finding the exact class/id of my menu with Firebug and inspectors, because I suspect it might be the problem, and I tried countless solutions without success. I even look after current-menu-item function on WPCodex, but still can't do it.

My site is: http://classwebdesign.hu/testing/

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The link to you site is not working, but the first part of your code is right.

If you find out the right class/id of your menu it should work. It would be something like this:

```
.menuClass .current-menu-item a {
    /*you code here*/
}
```

OR

```
#menuId .current-menu-item a {
    /*you code here*/
}
```